# HP Proliant BL460c Gen1 , Redhat 6.5 installation

Tags: redhat, hp, hp-proliant

I have been trying to install redhat 6.5 on HP Proliant BL460c Gen1, and when installation completes, it fails to boot from harddrive. It just gets stuck on "Trying to boot from harddrive (C:).  Does any one know if Redhat 6.5 is supported on the server?

Comment: How are you running the installation? Are you using a USB key? Network install? CD?

Comment: I used CD and USB with same results

Comment: Was it a USB CD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're installing your bootloader to the wrong place.

This sounds like a SCSI enumeration issue, so the important details are:

- What media you're installing from: USB and USB CDROM will shift the device names around *(e.g. /dev/sda, /dev/sdb)*.
- Either way, your server is a G1, so it has a Smart Array P400i or E200i RAID controller. Under RHEL 6.x, those will be discovered as /dev/cciss/cXdY. Please make sure you install your bootloader to that device during your installation.
- Be sure to [set the "Boot Volume"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mx0BS.jpg) in the Smart Array BIOS utility.
- Make sure nothing silly is connected to the system at POST time.

Comment: Thanx i was installing the bootloader at the wrong place. Its working now